# No source code is available for type in GWT (abstract class)

Tags: gwt

I have a business object (called Expense) that I am trying to use in my GWT application. I have it imported in the class, but when I compile, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Line 67: No source code is available for type com.app.pojo.Expense; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Is there anything special that I have to do (addition to gwt.xml?) to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I cannot use the gson library, nor the SimpleDateFormat class with gwt?

Comment: correct. There is a JSON implementation in GWT and AtuoBeans. There is also a replacement for SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

I dont' know how your `Expense` class looks like, but you can't use either `Gson` or `SimpleDateFormat` in GWT code. See the [JRE emulation list](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) of the only available types. You have to use both on the server. You can use [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) on client/shared sides.

I'm assuming you have already added `com.app.pojo` as a translatable package (i.e., using `source-path` in your XML module).